# How to ignore null fields while storing into mongo db using apache camel routing

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-camel

I am facing issue like while storing object to into database it being stored fields which are null also.

Is there any possibility to ignore null fields in the object in the save operation of camel routing.

Find sample snippet from camel routing xml.

```
<to uri="bean:processorBean?method=getRequest(${header.ccsRequest})"/>
<to uri="mongodb:myDb?database=test&amp;collection=test&amp;operation=save"/>
```

${header.ccsRequest} --> This will pass my pojo object to the method.
getRequest --> This method will do changes some changes in the pojo object.

In database after save operation:

```
{
    "action" : "Create",
    "urls" : null,
    "createModifyId" : "test",
    "createModifyDate" : "Tue Nov 17 17:29:07 GMT-03:00 2015",
    "completedDate" : null
}
```

Can you please help in ignoring the null fields like **urls** or **completeDate**. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there is more elegant approach, but I would do the following:

1. Add a new processor between  `bean:processorBean` and `mongodb:myDb`
2. Create a map from POJO using `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap`
3. Clean key-value pairs you dont need
4. Marshal the map to JSON and pass it to mongodb